# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while running Android activity in Unity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

After long fight with building project i stuck on launching android activity

logcat output:

```
I/Unity   (20479): Welcome on Android border
I/Unity   (20479): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/testapp/androidplugin/app/SplashScreen;
I/Unity   (20479): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/testapp/androidplugin/app/SplashScreen;
I/Unity   (20479):      at com.testapp.androidplugin.app.UnityBinder.foo(UnityBinder.java:16)
I/Unity   (20479):      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
I/Unity   (20479):      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source)
I/Unity   (20479):      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b.run(Unknown Source)
I/Unity   (20479): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.testapp.androidplugin.app.SplashScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.testapp.androidplugin.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.testapp.androidplugin.app-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, sy
stem/vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib/egl, system/lib/hw]]
I/Unity   (20479):      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
I/Unity   (20479):      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
I/Unity   (20479):      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
```

First line is from Java class, so something happen...

UnityBinder.class

```
public static void foo(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("Unity", "Welcome on Android border");
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, SplashScreen.class);
    activity.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

both classes are in the same package, I event tried with providing full path to package, but same result

```
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(200, 200, 400, 400), "Start"))
    {
        var androidJC = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    var jo = androidJC.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    var jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.testapp.androidplugin.app.UnityBinder");
    jc.CallStatic("foo", jo);
    }
```

SplashScreen is extended by AppCompatActivity

I used Java decompiler to look at files structure, and SplashScreen class exists there 
In Plugins -> Android directory I have appcompat-v7-23.1.1.aar, design-23.1.1.aar, classes (which is from my unpacked *.aar android module), rest and assets folder.

I'm using unity 5.3

Comment: Have you figured out the solution?

Comment: @jclova Have you figured out the solution?

Comment: Hi Jakub, have you figured out the solution for this problem?

Comment: It was 2 years ago and as I remember I stuck on it and we abandon this project, to many problems comes up

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it. I copied appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar & support-v4-25.3.1.aar to my Assets folder but it didn't work. Then I switched to Gradle build system in Unity and added following lines under dependencies.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

It should like this

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
**DEPS**}
```